# I have to reinstall QT creator every time I want to use it?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm running 64 bit ubuntu, when I first open QT creator it works, but then as soon as I close and reopen it, it can no longer find the 64 bit libraries, and the preferences only show the 32 bit kit as selectable, then I have to uninstall and reinstall it for it to work.  Every time I want to open it.

What do I do about this?

Comment: File a bug report? Is this Qt Creator of Ubuntu, or Qt Creator installed by Qt SDK installer (which one), as that determines here you should file the bug report. Which Ubuntu? Try the other one and see if it works better?

Comment: Which ubuntu version, which qtcreator version (from apt or downloaded from the website). What error message